# Wso2 esb tryit tool works but testing with SOAP UI for same proxy does not work

Tags: wso2-esb

Iteration mediator works with WSo2 Tryit tool but when the same message is sent through SOAP UI the proxy it does not iterate. My proxy service is very simple it has a xslt mediator and then does the iteration. Do I need to change the content type?

Answer (score 1):

Can you paster your proxy service source code.
Try it tool is a evolving tool, but you should always do your testing from SOAP UI.

This is the sample format :-

```
<iterate expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request" preservePayload="true"
     attachPath="//m0:getQuote"
     xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
<target>
    <sequence>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address
                    uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </sequence>
</target>
```

Comment: <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TEST_ESB" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <xslt key="gov:/repository/transform/OrderRequest.xslt" />
         <log level="full" />
         <sequence key="Sequence3" />
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>

Comment: <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Sequence3" trace="enable">
   <log>
      <property name="Sequence3" value="Sequence3" />
   </log>
   <iterate xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" continueParent="false" expression="//dat:OracleOrderRequest/dat:EventData" id="IT1" sequential="false">
      <target endpoint="Event_ep" />
   </iterate>
 
</sequence>